# Augmented reality in iPhone that can show 3d models

Tags: iphone, objective-c, augmented-reality

I am developing an application in which the user can "collect" treasures based on coordinates using the iPhone camera and the following AR toolkit library:

https://github.com/nielswh/iPhone-AR-Toolkit

In the demo project you can see cities connected to coordinates like London, Paris and so on.

I want to add a couple of treasures connected to coordinates, when you come close to the treasure, let's say 20 meters the user should see the treasure in 3d format.

So if the user are going to collect micro waves and come closer than 20 meters, the micro wave should appear on the camera as an overlay. Then a button should appear as an overlay on the camera named "collect treasure" and then the treasure is collected.

It doesn't necessarily have to be 3d objects, just images.

I wonder, is this possible?

---

### Edit #1

I have played around with Wikitude (which don't support 3d models for iPhone), Junaio (which supports 3d models but you can't create a stand-a-lone app) and Layar (the same as Junaio).

Does anybody know some other AR Toolkits whichs supports adding 3d models to the screen and that can be a stand-a-lone app on the app store?

---

### Edit #2

I just noticed that Layar accually has support for a standalone app with their Layar Player SDK. They also has support for 3d models, I will try if this works very soon.

---

### Edit #3

Adding 3d models worked like a charm! But Layar Player SDK doesn't allow us to customize the interface, which is a huge problem for us... I'm now looking for another AR browser/toolkit/api in this thread:

[Treasure hunt in Augmented Reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803468/augmented-reality-browser-api-toolkit-that-supports-the-following)

Comment: StackExchange proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30436/augmented-reality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Creating the AR application itself requires a bit of high school math (atan), some 2D rotations with Quartz,  and some trickery, like doing a [low-pass filter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html) to the signal from accelerometers to avoid trembling. Work with lat/long as cartesian coordinates instead spherical trigonometry, the extra precission is not worth it. You can receive touches on your overlay, fake 3D with 2D rotations, or present a [opengl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLGravity/Listings/Classes_GLGravityView_m.html) overlay.

Comment: I have tried the Wikitude example project in iPhone now. It works great but I want to know how to add 3d objects to a certain location. I'm researching this right now..

Comment: Take the lat/long of yourself and the target, imaging a right triangle from your position to the position of the object, calculate the atan to get the angle, compare with the angle of your compass, calculate the euclidian distance, scale the object, paint it if you are pointing towards the object +- half the field vision of your camera. One problem: position accuracy depends on AGPS, it could be accurate or be off hundreds of meters. That's a limitation you can't overcome. See the GLGravity example from Apple and overlay it on the UIImagePickerController.

Comment: Hi Jano. Thanks for the info but this is way to advanced for me. I thought that maybe some Augmented Reality API had this built in. I haven't seen anyone yet though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Although you'll have lots of stuff to do if you use that framework. You can try Layar, that already has the Layar player to use it as if you included a youtube video inside your app, but in the AR paradigm. Layar natively offers proximity triggers and 3D objects without any development effort from your side! I would give it a try.

Comment: Hi Ruben. Can I still use it as my app on the app store if I use Layar? It looks like you have to use your application inside the Layer-app for iPhone?

Comment: It looks like I have to create a web service that returns all the POIs. I'm more intrested in a iPhone toolkit/API so everything happends in the iPhone app.

Comment: Well, first you can use the Layar Player to use their AR technology inside your propietary app and for free. Then, to add your POIs, you can use your own server as you point out but you can create them trough services like Hoppala. If you want your POIs to be local and static, you have no option: the iPhone-AR-kit (or maybe Wikitude).

Comment: I have tried Wikitude example project in iPhone now. It works great but I want to know how to add 3d objects to a certain location. I'm researching this right now...