# Treasure hunt in Augmented Reality

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, augmented-reality

I'm looking for an augmented reality browser/toolkit/api that supports the following:

- Adding fixed 3d models such as a treasure-chest.
- Possible image recognition of this treasure-chest so the iPhone knows when you're looking at it.
- Specify altitude on a 3d model so it can be positioned on the ground or the second floor in an apartment building for example.
- It must have support for "migrating" it to a standalone app that can be published on the app store.
- The ability to customize the camera overlay with own buttons, huds, text and other UIViews.
- Support for both iPhone and Android.

I have tried Wikitude which doesn't have support for 3d models in iPhone.
I have tried Junaio which doesn't support to create a standalone app using their browser.
I have tried Layar Player SDK, and asked the question on their community if I can customize the interface with own buttons etc.
I have tried the artoolkit on github.

None of the libraries I've tried have support for all my demands.

Am I looking for too much here?
Is there something I've missed using Layar, Wikitude and Junaio?

Comment: StackExchange proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30436/augmented-reality

Comment: it's a proposal for a stackexchange site dedicated to Augmented Reality questions, it's kinda new and needs love from technical experts (programmers, designers, scientists, etc.) involved in creating Augmented Reality applications and techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specify altitude on a 3d model so it
>   can be positioned on the ground or the
>   second floor in a apartment building
>   for example.

Can you break this down? Do you want the phone to recognize it's on the second floor, at a particular location within the building?  In general altitude is surprisingly tricky, and indoor positioning is very approximate - in the absence of indoor GPS repeaters or some other indoor positioning mechanisms which would probably require a lot of additional effort (bluetooth beacons, WiFi triangulation etc) this might be infeasible - in general, and not just given a particular AR library.

I think the Junaio libraries cover the other bases - CV recognition of a (prepared) object, stand-alone application packaging, customizable UI, and iPhone and Android support.

Comment: I have searched a lot but can't find the "tutorial" for creating a stand-alone app with Junaio? Can you point me towards that direction please?

Thank you for your answer. I knew that the altitutde example would be little too much. In fact, it's not important to position an object inside a building on a certain floor. I just want to be able to position for example a treasure chest in the woods on the ground.

Comment: Sorry, "Juniao" was a brain-fart, I meant Metaio's mobile SDK - http://www.metaio.com/software/mobile-sdk/

Comment: Alright! I've read about Metaio mobile SDK for a  while now, but where can I download the "toolkit"? Is it free? I can only download a demo version in which I can't edit the Base SDK so I can't try it out on my device. I really hope Metaio will work for me :)

Comment: I think you have to contact them directly for a quote on pricing/licensing fees, and agree those before you get to use the full SDK.

Comment: Alright, I will. Do you know why it is like that? It's weird that after my research on three days I've never heard of Metaio thus they support everything I wrote in my thread! Even if Metaio costs a little, I will buy it. Thank you so much for the info dabhaid!

Comment: Metaio are the developers of Junaio - they're mostly operate on a  business-to-business model, where they facilitate e.g. 3rd party ad campaigns with their technology. I guess they offer pricing on request to adapt to different clients. Glad to help, good luck with your application!

Comment: Aha alright. Thanks for the info. The "problem" is that I'm doing this application for a client of mine, I wonder if I can get access anyway from Metaio. I have to write a nice letter to them :)

Comment: @Marsson What do you mean? :)

Comment: I called them about licensing. I am developing some stuff in AR too... I almost felt out of my chair when they told me the price...

Comment: @Marsson how much? (ballpark)

Comment: The pioneer in AR metaio(Developers of Junaio) will release a free version of the metaio Mobile SDK (Q4/2011). :)